# NODEJS - Send Byte Array as Response to data received

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a Node JS application that uses TCP communication using net module.

```
var net = require('net');
```

I received data successfully from the net module. The issue that i face is that I need to send a response data back to the TCP sender as a 4 byte array.

For example, i get a packet from the Device with the data 16. Now i need to send to the sender binary 4 byte data.

The data i need to send should look like this. '00000016'. Data has to be received at the sender as binary data.

Comment: Try using this https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Comment: @lazar , I tried using buffer. The out put comes like <Buffer 10 10 10 10>. Where as we need to get the result as 0x00000010 or 0x00000016 (based on the value given by the sender device.

Answer (score 0):

I had done a lot of research on the topic and found a NodeJs Module - binutils64 can respond to data in binary format.

```
const binutils = require('binutils64');
```